# Modify a class name in HTML with JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I just want to modify the source code of a website.
Looks like this : 
[image: proof] 
I'm trying to make a chrome extension that does this every single time I load the webpage 
Just changing briefly `<body class="web">` to `<body class="web dark"` I know it's just an append.
But I know nothing about websites and find nothing usefull on google.
I have inside my `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "description": "changes something",
    "version": "1.0",
    "page_action": 
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "untitled"
    }
}
```

And in `index.html` I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <title>Dark Mode</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("class=web").replaceWith("class=web dark");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Explanations will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.
First I got rid of JQuery because when putting it on a `.js` file it just doesn't work.
Don´t know why and don't care won't use it again. I got rid of it because it depends on a html file for working.

This single line of code is all I wanted :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = "web dark";
```

And for the `manifest.json` you can read a really good example [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).